# How to create app as service in iPhone

Tags: ios, boot

I want help for one of my apps. The app is required to execute small local notification when the device is booted or started.

I dont want an app to be launched to execute the predefined local notification code.

So how could we can do it in iOS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible using iOS unless the device is jailbroken *and I do praise the steve for that*.